# Cordova AJAX 404 Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

I'm developing an android application using cordova and therefore I also need AJAX requests to happen. I am using jQuery for the requests and after updating the index.php security policies I made it to connect my app to a remote server. But now I receive a error 404 - Not found when starting a AJAX request.
Could the error be related to the data I POST to the server?
The url is correct and I have enabled the whitelist plugin.

EDIT:

```
function ajaxrequestlogin() {
    var login_username=$("#username").val();
    var login_password=$("#password").val();
    var dataString="username="+login_username+"&password="+login_password;
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.my-url.de/path/to/myapi.php",
    data: dataString,
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function(){ $("#message").html('Verbinde...');},
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);},

    success: function(data){
        if(data=="success") {
            window.localStorage.setItem(loggedin, true);
            window.localStorage.setItem(username, login_username);
            window.localStorage.setItem(password, login_password);
            alert("Erfolgreich eingeloggt als "+login_username);
        }
        else if(data=="wrong_userorpass") {
            alert("Username und Passwort stimmen nicht überein!");
        }
        else if(data=="failed") {
            alert("Ups! Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten. Bitte versuche es erneut.");
        }
    }
    });
    return false;
}
```

The application should send username and password to the server which authenticates the credentials and returns either success or wrong_userorpass by using

```
echo "success";
```

for example.
Do I have to change something in my API's PHP script to make the option no-cache work or should it work fine without any intervention?

Comment: Unfortunately, you did not provide much information.  But I suspect that the Ajax request url is not what you think it should be.  Have you tried the same request from a different client (like Postman, for example)?

Comment: Nope, will try this in the afternoon and I'll post some code, too. I think that should provide you some details to solve the problem. And what do you mean with "the ajax request url is not what I think it should be"?

Comment: @pcfreakxxx did you have proper access origin setting in config.XML?

Comment: @Gandhi I didn't change a thing on that so it's access-origin=*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay after some hours of trying around, changing security policies and config.xml I finally solved the problem so I'll just share it to you 'cause I think it's pretty a common problem when trying to use Ajax with cordova applications.
While trying to fix the problem I read like 10 forum posts of people who have updated their cordova and thereafter Ajax dropped 404 errors. The solution for those guys was always to just install the `cordova-plugin-whitelist` plugin. For me (I downloaded version 6.3) this plugin was already installed and activated so I did not bother about those answers. After trying around this evening I realized that everything was ok with my scripts and it had to be a cordova specific issue (I tested it with a browser version of the ajax request) so I just typed
`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist`.
It installed (even the plugin was already installed and active) and immediately thereafter everything worked as it should.
So even if you think the whitelist-plugin cannot be the problem: just try install it again and it should work fine.

Comment: After 90 mins of trying to figure out why the hell my app wouldn't connect to anything, I found this post, reinstalled cordova-plugin-whitelist and it works! Thanks for sharing :-)

Comment: @james-geldart Great to hear :)